# The Operators in Calculator Javascript isn't working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a calculator for FreeCodeCamp in Javascript. I'm having problem with one part of the code. When I add an operator such as "-", "+", "x", and so on, the numbers in the history section repeat itself. For example, if I entered "5", "5" appears in the history area. Then I entered "+" and the history shows "5+5+".

Additionally, I wanted the calculator to work similar to the calculator found in Mac computers. In other words, if I entered "5", then entered "+", I wanted the "5" to stay in the display area while "5+" shows up in the history area until next number is pressed. Then it will display next number while the history shows "5+6". How do I solve both problems?

Here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/MEQvqv

You can see it also here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var mainMath = "0";
  var subMath = "0";
  update();
  var period = /\./;
  
  $("button").click(function(){
    calculate($(this).attr("value"));
  });
  
  function calculate(keyitem) {
    switch(keyitem) {
      case "clear":
        clearScreen();
        break;
      case "plusminus":
        plusminusScreen();
        break;
      case "%":
        percentageScreen();
        break;
      case "/":
      case "*":
      case "+":
      case "-":
        addOperator(keyitem);
        break;
      case "0":
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
      case "5":
      case "6":
      case "7":
      case "8":
      case "9":
      case ".":
        addNumber(keyitem);
        break;
      case "=":
        solveEqual();
        break;
    }
    update();
    };
 
  function clearScreen() {
     mainMath = "0";
     subMath = "0";
  };
  
  function plusminusScreen() {
     mainMath = -1 * mainMath;
     subMath = -1 * subMath;
  };
  
  function addNumber(keyitem) {
    if (keyitem == "."){
      if(mainMath == 0 && subMath == 0) {
        mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
        subMath = "0" + keyitem;
        return;
      }
    }
    if (mainMath == "0" && subMath == "0"){
      mainMath=keyitem;
      subMath=keyitem;
      return;
    }
    mainMath+=keyitem;
    subMath+=keyitem;
  };
  
  function addOperator(keyitem){
    addNumber(keyitem);
    subMath += mainMath;
    mainMath = keyitem;
  };
  
  function update(){
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = mainMath;
  document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = subMath;
};
  
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');
h1, h2, h3, p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 160px 0;
}
.calculatorbox {
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.calheader {
  text-align: center;
}
.calwindow {
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */
  flex-direction:         column;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.entry {
  font-size: 4em;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
.entryhistory {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.entry p, .entryhistory p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
 
sub {
  bottom: -0em;
}
.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.key {
  width: 65px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.key.btnspan {
  width: 130px;
}
.key.topcolor {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}
.key.orange {
  background: #ff8c00;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
      <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS -->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The part that I'm having problem with is this:

```
function addOperator(keyitem){
    addNumber(keyitem);
    subMath += mainMath;
    mainMath = keyitem;
  };
```

******************************UPDATE**********************************
So far I was able to resolve the history area problem. However, I am unable to solve the display problem. The problem now is every time I click on a number such as "7", then click on an operator such as "+", the number in the display area changed back to "0". Additionally, after the operator, I then click on another number such as "3", it shows up as "03" in the display area... Here's my updated code:

```
function addOperator(keyitem){
    if(mainMath == "0"){
      /*subMath === "0";*/
      return;
    }
    /*addNumber(keyitem);*/
    subMath += keyitem;
    mainMath = "0";
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, you have to separate the displaying logic and the calculation logic. What you want is:

- when you type a number => display the number OR the result (separate function, separate variables)
- number or operator => calculate (another function, other variables)

In your code, the two logics are mixed.

Try to help you as best as you can. You can use a debugger and use it step by step or add utilies function in your code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    // My check point function
    function ckval(name, where){
      if (undefined != where) { where += ' ' }
      console.log(name + " " + where + "= ", eval(name))
}
  
    var mainMath = "0";
    var subMath = "0";
    update();
    var period = /\./;
  
    $("button").click(function(){
      calculate($(this).attr("value"));
    });
  
    function calculate(keyitem) {
      switch(keyitem) {
        case "clear":
          clearScreen();
          break;
        case "plusminus":
          plusminusScreen();
          break;
        case "%":
          percentageScreen();
          break;
        case "/":
        case "*":
        case "+":
        case "-":
          addOperator(keyitem);
          break;
        case "0":
        case "1":
        case "2":
        case "3":
        case "4":
        case "5":
        case "6":
        case "7":
        case "8":
        case "9":
        case ".":
          addNumber(keyitem);
          break;
        case "=":
          solveEqual();
          break;
      }
      update();
      };
 
    function clearScreen() {
       mainMath = "0";
       subMath = "0";
    };
  
    function plusminusScreen() {
       mainMath = -1 * mainMath;
       subMath = -1 * subMath;
    };
  
    function addNumber(keyitem) {
      console.log("-> addNumber("+keyitem+")",); // <- method
      if (keyitem == "."){
        if(mainMath == 0 && subMath == 0) {
          mainMath = "0" + keyitem;
          subMath = "0" + keyitem;
          return;
        }
      }
      if (mainMath == "0" && subMath == "0"){
        mainMath=keyitem;
        subMath=keyitem;
        return;
      }
      mainMath+=keyitem;
      subMath+=keyitem;
      
      ckval('mainMath', 'at bottom of addNumber'); // <- checkPoint
      ckval('subMath', 'at bottom of addNumber');  // <- checkPoint
      
    };
  
    function addOperator(keyitem){
      console.log("-> addOperation("+keyitem+")");
      ckval('mainMath'); // <- checkPoint
      ckval('subMath');  // <- checkPoint
      addNumber(keyitem);
      ckval('mainMath', 'after addNumber'); // <- checkPoint
      ckval('subMath', 'after addNumber');  // <- checkPoint
      subMath += mainMath;
      mainMath = keyitem;
      ckval('mainMath', 'at bottom of addOperator'); // <- checkPoint
      ckval('subMath', 'at bottom of addOperator');  // <- checkPoint
    };
  
    function update(){
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = mainMath;
    document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = subMath;
  };
  
  
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');h1, h2, h3, p {  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}html, body{  height:100%;  margin: 0;  background-color: #ffffff;}.wrapper {  width: 100%;  height: 100%;  position: relative;  display:flex;  flex-direction:column;  justify-content:center;  align-items:center;  background-repeat: no-repeat;    background-size: cover;  background-position: center center;  padding: 160px 0;}.calculatorbox {  width: 260px;  margin: 0 auto;  border: 1px solid #000000;}.calheader {  text-align: center;}.calwindow {  background: #000000;  position: relative;  display: -webkit-box;  display: -moz-box;  display: -ms-flexbox;  display: -webkit-flex;  display: flex;   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */  flex-direction:         column;  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;  justify-content: flex-end;  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;  align-items: flex-end;  padding: 10px 0;  box-sizing: border-box;}.entry {  font-size: 4em;  display: block;  line-height: 1em;}.entryhistory {  font-size: 1em;  padding-right: 5px;}.entry p, .entryhistory p {  margin: 0;  color: #ffffff;}sup {  top: -0.5em;}sub {  bottom: -0em;}.row {  clear: both;  width: 100%;  display: flex;}button {  display: inline-block;  border: none;  padding: 0;  outline: none;  cursor: pointer;}.key {  width: 65px;  height: 60px;  font-size: 22px;  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  box-sizing: border-box;}.key.btnspan {  width: 130px;}.key.topcolor {  background: #d9d9d9;}.key.orange {  background: #ff8c00;  color: #ffffff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"><div class="calheader"><h2>Simple Calculator</h2></div><div class="calculatorbox"><div class="calwindow">  <!-- ENTRY BOX -->  <div class="entry">    <p id="answer"></p>  </div>  <div class="entryhistory">    <p id="history"></p>  </div></div><!-- BUTTONS --><div class="calbuttons">  <div class="row">    <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>    <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>    <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>    <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>  </div>  <div class="row">    <button class="key" value="7">7</button>    <button class="key" value="8">8</button>    <button class="key" value="9">9</button>    <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>  </div>  <div class="row">    <button class="key" value="4">4</button>    <button class="key" value="5">5</button>    <button class="key" value="6">6</button>    <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>  </div>  <div class="row">    <button class="key" value="1">1</button>    <button class="key" value="2">2</button>    <button class="key" value="3">3</button>    <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>  </div>  <div class="row">    <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>    <button class="key" value=".">.</button>    <button class="key orange" value="=">=</button>  </div></div></div></div>
```

Doing that, you see immediatly where the problem happen. Here's: `subMath = at bottom of addOperator 8+8+`.

Then easy to fix.

---

Maybe another approach could help you too. See the one below (not exactly the same behaviour, but you could change it easily):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      
        // +stackOperations+ keeps every user action
    let stackOperations = []
        // +currentDispQueue+ keeps trace of the current top display
      , currentDispQueue  = '' ;
    
    // To catch the user click event  
    $("button").click(function(){ catchClick($(this).attr("value")); });
  
    /**
      * Catch the user click
      * Note: 'calculate' is a less good name for this fonction
      * // function calculate(keyitem) {
      */
    function catchClick(keyitem) {
      switch(keyitem) {
        case "clear": return reset() ; // clearScreen is actually a `reset`
        case "plusminus":
          if (stackOperations.length) {
            currentDispQueue = '' ;
            updateUserDisplay('-' + currentDispQueue) ;
            stackOperations.push({type: 'operator', value: '*-1'})
          }; break;
        case "/":case "*": case "+": case "-": case '.':
          currentDispQueue = '' ;
          stackOperations.push({type: 'operator', value: keyitem}); break;
        case "=": 
          return displayTotal();
      default:
        if (keyitem >= 0 && keyitem < 10) {
          stackOperations.push({type: 'number', value: parseInt(keyitem)})
          displayCurrentQueue( currentDispQueue + keyitem ); // "6"+"3" => "63"
        }
      };
      displayCurrentHistory(); // always (each user action => reaction)
    }
    
    /**
      * Display the result of the calc
      */
    function displayTotal()
    {
      displayCurrentQueue(calculProceed());
    }
    
    /**
      * Reset App
      */
    function reset() {
      stackOperations = [] ;
      currentDispQueue  = '' ;
      displayCurrentHistory('&nbsp;') ;
      displayCurrentQueue() ;
    };
    reset();
  
    /**
      * Display methods
      */
    function displayCurrentQueue(displayedValue){
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = displayedValue || '0';
      if (displayedValue) currentDispQueue = displayedValue ;
    }
    function displayCurrentHistory(){
      document.getElementById("history").innerHTML = history();
    }
            
    /**
      * Calc methods
      *
      */
    /** Return the 'history', i.e. the calcul as a string */
    function history() {
      return stackOperations.reduce( (x, y) => { return x + y.value } , '');
    }
    /** Eval the history and return it */
    function calculProceed() {
      return eval(history());
    }
    
  
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400');h1, h2, h3, p {  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}html, body{  height:100%;  margin: 0;  background-color: #ffffff;}.wrapper {  width: 100%;  height: 100%;  position: relative;  display:flex;  flex-direction:column;  justify-content:center;  align-items:center;  background-repeat: no-repeat;    background-size: cover;  background-position: center center;  padding: 160px 0;}.calculatorbox {  width: 260px;  margin: 0 auto;  border: 1px solid #000000;}.calheader {  text-align: center;}.calwindow {  background: #000000;  position: relative;  display: -webkit-box;  display: -moz-box;  display: -ms-flexbox;  display: -webkit-flex;  display: flex;   -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari */  flex-direction:         column;  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;  justify-content: flex-end;  -webkit-align-items: flex-end;  align-items: flex-end;  padding: 10px 0;  box-sizing: border-box;}.entry {  font-size: 4em;  display: block;  line-height: 1em;}.entryhistory {  font-size: 1em;  padding-right: 5px;}.entry p, .entryhistory p {  margin: 0;  color: #ffffff;}sup {  top: -0.5em;}sub {  bottom: -0em;}.row {  clear: both;  width: 100%;  display: flex;}button {  display: inline-block;  border: none;  padding: 0;  outline: none;  cursor: pointer;}.key {  width: 65px;  height: 60px;  font-size: 22px;  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);  box-sizing: border-box;}.key.btnspan {  width: 130px;}.key.topcolor {  background: #d9d9d9;}.key.orange {  background: #ff8c00;  color: #ffffff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"><div class="calheader"><h2>Simple Calculator</h2></div><div class="calculatorbox"><div class="calwindow">  <!-- ENTRY BOX -->  <div class="entry">    <p id="answer"></p>  </div>  <div class="entryhistory">    <p id="history"></p>  </div></div><!-- BUTTONS --><div class="calbuttons">  <div class="row">    <button class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>    <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>    <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>    <button class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>  </div>  <div class="row">    <button class="key" value="7">7</button>    <button class="key" value="8">8</button>    <button class="key" value="9">9</button>    <button class="key orange" value="*">×</button>  </div>  <div class="row">    <button class="key" value="4">4</button>    <button class="key" value="5">5</button>    <button class="key" value="6">6</button>    <button class="key orange" value="-">−</button>  </div>  <div class="row">    <button class="key" value="1">1</button>    <button class="key" value="2">2</button>    <button class="key" value="3">3</button>    <button class="key orange" value="+">+</button>  </div>  <div class="row">    <button class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>    <button class="key" value=".">.</button><button class="key orange" value="=">=</button></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Please see my Updated information at bottom of my question. I fixed the history area but I'm still having problem with my Display area...

Comment: @KristinaBressler, I joined to the end of my answer another way to do the work. It could be interesting for you. Take a look,  please.